# NodeJs/Express and Module Scope

Tags: node.js, express

When I require a module in the main `app.js` file on an Express project, are those modules accessible from other modules? Sounds confusing, let me give an example:

In my app.js I have the following:

```
var iniparser = require('iniparser');
var config = iniparser.parseSync('./config.ini');
```

Which works fine if use `config.port` within the `app.js` file. But when trying to access `config` from the `routes.js` file, it's not available.

So my question is, is the scope limited to the module/file other modules are included in? And if I wanted to parse the `config.ini` would I have to include the module in any module/file I intend to use the 'iniparser' module.

I hope I've not confused anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of a variable declared with

```
var xxx = yyy;
```

is limited to the module/file where it is declared (or the function where it is declared, if it is declared inside a function.)

In your case, you have to add the two lines in every file/module where you need it.

As an optimization, and to avoid parsing the config file several times, you could have a config.js file

```
var iniparser = require('iniparser');
module.exports = iniparser.parseSync('./config.ini'); // executed only once
```

And then require your config in all files/modules where it is needed

```
var config = require('./config');
console.log(config.port);
```